# What do the String... and Void... keywords mean?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between `String` and `String...` and what is the difference between `Void` and `Void...` in this context?

```
class AddStringsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            for (String item: items){
                publishProgress(item);
                SystemClock.sleep(200);
            }
            return(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item){
            ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){
            Toast.makeText(Cap15Asyncer.this,"Completed!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: how about a little more context?

Comment: @GEOCHET - I think you edited the question out of context...

Comment: @MByD: I think you should have just edited the question instead of leaving a comment for someone else to edit...

Comment: @GEOCHET - maybe you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item){
    ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);
}
```

`String... item` Means that the method takes an arbitrary number of Strings (including 0 Strings).  So this method can be called with any number of strings as input, and it will add them all to the listAdapter, like an array.  If the method was:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String item){
    ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item);
}
```

Then it would take exactly one String, (note the add method has changed accordingly).

Answer (score 7):

It means that there might be a variable number of `String` parameters in the function call, it is called [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 1):

As you are mentioning `void`, I would assume that you are asking about the return type on a method.  `void` means that there will be no value returning when called and `string` means that a type of string will be returning from your method.

Return types explicitly tell the calling object *what kind* of data to not only expect to get back, but to guarentee.

Answer (score -1):

Taking into account your code

```
kprotected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {             
for (String item: items){        
  publishProgress(item);                
 SystemClock.sleep(200);          
   }
```

`Void` means that there will be no return
This would however return something

```
kprotected something doInBackground(<your parameters here>){
//do your work    
return something
}
```

String is something that is stored as text.
Your case each item that is stored as a `string` in items.(the bigger picture) will have work done on it.

**EDIT:**

When passing in multiple arguements as in the String array using `String...` automates the process of multiple arguements being used. Notice how it is not used in the last method.

And yes as mentioned in another answer this is [Varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)